# Table dependencies SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How do I find dependencies to a database object within the same database server but not same database?

E.g. if I have a table `dbo.table1` in `Database1` and it is referenced in a stored procedure `dbo.SPROC_1` in `Database2`.

I used

```
 SELECT 
     referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
     referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
 FROM 
     sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.table1', 'OBJECT');
```

This only returns dependencies in `Database1`.

Comment: You can't easily. Dependencies are only within a given database. But you can use something like SQL Search from Redgate to search for references to the the other database. No matter how you slice is the dependencies for an external database (even on the same server) will have to be mapped by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use below query which can give your the list of dependency in all the DB. however it may give additional rows so you need to modify your search criterion accordingly-

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)  , @tabName varchar(100)
select @tabName = 'Sales.Customer'
SELECT @command = 'USE ? select   distinct db_name(), object_name(id)  from ?.dbo.syscomments(nolock) where text like ''%'+@tabName+'%''
union all select   distinct db_name(), name  from ?.sys.synonyms(nolock) where replace(replace(base_object_name,''['','''') ,'']'','''') like ''%'+@tabName+'%''' 
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Comment: This works most of the time but will still miss dependencies if the other database is using an alias instead of the table name.

Comment: I meant to say synonym, not alias. :)

Comment: Modified the above query to take care of synonyms.